# Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: xml, powershell, windows-server-2016

I am trying to use Set-Content to create an xml document with a variable being passed.  I am able to run the following command from my own desktop (windows 10) without issue.  But running it on a server (Windows Server 2016) I get an error.

```
Set-Location "C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent"
$MyVariable = '123456'
Set-Content C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parameters>
    <parameter name='url' value='https://dev.service.com/'/>
    <parameter name='mid.instance.username' value='Server'/>
    <parameter secure='true' name='mid.instance.password' value='$MyVariable'/>
    <parameter name='name' value='Test'/>
    <parameter name='mid_sys_id' value=''/>
</parameters>"`
```

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parameters>
    <parameter name='url' value='https://dev.service-now.com/'/>
    <parameter name='mid.instance.username' value='Server'/>
    <parameter secure='true' name='mid.instance.password' value='123456'/>
    <parameter name='name' value='Test'/>
    <parameter name='mid_sys_id' value=''/>
</parameters>'.
At line:16 char:1
+ Set-Content C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml "<?xml version=' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

In both cases I am running the command as Admin.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PowerShell 5.1, apart from the final backtick in your code and the unquoted path while this path contains a space character, I cannot reproduce that error.

Since you want to write XML, why not use the xml `.Save()` method for this?

```
$MyVariable = '123456'
[xml]$xml =  @"
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parameters>
    <parameter name='url' value='https://dev.service.com/'/>
    <parameter name='mid.instance.username' value='Server'/>
    <parameter secure='true' name='mid.instance.password' value='$MyVariable'/>
    <parameter name='name' value='Test'/>
    <parameter name='mid_sys_id' value=''/>
</parameters>
"@

$xml.Save('C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml')
```

If you must do this with Set-Content, I'd advise using a Here-String:

```
$MyVariable = '123456'
Set-Content -Path 'C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml' -Value @"
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parameters>
    <parameter name='url' value='https://dev.service.com/'/>
    <parameter name='mid.instance.username' value='Server'/>
    <parameter secure='true' name='mid.instance.password' value='$MyVariable'/>
    <parameter name='name' value='Test'/>
    <parameter name='mid_sys_id' value=''/>
</parameters>
"@ -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63883918/45375) shows viable solutions, but to address the **root cause**:

**Since target path `C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml` contains a *space* character, you must *quote* it** so that `Set-Content` recognizes it as a *single* argument.

Thus,

```
# !! BROKEN - quoting of the path is missing.
Set-Content C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml "<?xml ..."
```

must be (note the single-quoting of the path):

```
Set-Content 'C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml' "<?xml ..."
```

---

`Set-Content C:\MID Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml "<?xml ..."` is effectively the same as
`Set-Content 'C:\MID' 'Server\prodAgent\agent\config.xml' "<?xml ..."`, i.e. *3* arguments are passed, whereas [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)only supports *2* positional arguments (`-Path` and `-Value`). Therefore, PowerShell complains about `"<?xml ..."` as an unexpected 3rd argument.

See also: [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules).

Comment: thanks for the clarification, any idea why it works from my desktop but not from windows server?  That's the part that was really throwing me.

Comment: @adamsummerville: The only plausible explanation is that the file path you used on the desktop happened not to contain spaces.